# How can I merge Same Range from each file in a folder onto a master sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, directory

I modified the code this way... it gathers data from all the sheets and finds only the rows that have data, BUT now I am having a problem modifying the range with each pass so that it is equal to the number of rows that do have value (found with (values[row][0] != '')).  I have put a ??? in the spot where I am trying to have a variable height.

```
function getAllData() {
var folder = DocsList.getFolderById("folderid");
var contents = folder.getFiles();
Logger.log("file length: " + contents.length);

var file;
var data;

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base")
sheet.clearContents();



var numOfFiles = contents.length;

for (var i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++) {
file = contents[i];
Logger.log("count: "  + i);

var theFileType = file.getFileType();
Logger.log("theFileType: " + theFileType);

if (theFileType==DocsList.FileType.SPREADSHEET) {

  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var lastLine = sheet2.getLastRow();
var values = sheet2.getRange('A3:J').getValues();
var formulas = sheet2.getRange('A3:J').getFormulas();

    var data = [];

      for(var row = 0 ; row < (values).length ; row++){

 var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
if (values[row][0] != '')  {

for(var col = 0 ; col < formulas[row].length ; col++){
    if(formulas[row][col] != '')
      {values[row][col] = formulas[row][col]};


  data.push(values[row]);}
  if(data.length > 0)
  sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1, ???, data[0].length).setValues(data);

  } 
}

  };
}}
```

Comment: You have something named `posheet` and `commitsheet`, but I don't see where either of those are defined or assigned a reference.  Is there some other code you didn't post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `getValue()` as opposed to `getValues()` (With a letter "s" on the end)

```
var onecell = posheet.getRange('B4').getValue();
```

The documentation states:

> getValue()  - Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range.

The parameter for `getRange()` is kind of tricky and not well documented.
For example this:

```
getRange(2, 3, 6, 4)
```

gets a range from C2 to G8.  Figure that out.  The first number is the number 2, which is for the row 2. The second number is 3, for the third column (which is C).  The third and fourth numbers are relative to the first two numbers.

Also, you are using: `appendRow([array])` which uses an array for the parameter.  So you must make sure that the data is in the form of an array, or use something else.

Here is the link for getValues:

[Google Documentation - getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

The example is this code:

```
 // The code below will get the values for the range C2:G8
 // in the active spreadsheet.  Note that this will be a javascript array.
 var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 3, 6, 4).getValues();
 Logger.log(values[0][0]);
```

Here is code that seems to work:

```
function getAllData() {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolderById("Your file ID");
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  Logger.log("file length: " + contents.length);
  
  var file;
  var data;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  sheet.clearContents();

  sheet.appendRow(["Value from Sheet One", "Range of values from Sheet Two"]);

  var numOfFiles = contents.length;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++) {
    file = contents[i];
    Logger.log("count: "  + i);
    
    //Reset to null on every iteration 
    var onecell = null;
    var theRange = null;
    
    var theFileType = file.getFileType();
    Logger.log("theFileType: " + theFileType);
    
    if (theFileType==DocsList.FileType.SPREADSHEET) {
      var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("Sheet2");

     // The code below will get the values for the range A3:A9
     // in the active spreadsheet.  Note that this will be a javascript array.
 
      onecell = sheet1.getRange('B4').getValue();
      theRange = sheet2.getRange(1,3,1,6).getValues();

      Logger.log('onecell: ' + onecell);
      Logger.log('onecell[0][0]: ' + onecell[0][0]);
      
      Logger.log('theRange: ' + theRange)
      Logger.log('theRange[0][0]: ' + theRange[0][0])
      
      var multipleValues = [theRange[0][0], theRange[0][1], theRange[0][2], theRange[0][3], theRange[0][4]];
      Logger.log('multipleValues: ' + multipleValues);
      
      sheet.appendRow([onecell, "'" + multipleValues]);
    };
  }
}
```

In the first column, it only enters one value into the sheet cell.  In the second column, the cell gets multiple values put into it from the row.  In other words, and entire rows values, and combined and put into one cell.  I think that's what you want from the code.

If you try to put an array into a spreadsheet cell, instead of showing the array of values as text, it shows something like an object.  So I put a quote in front of the values so the cell formatting would default to text.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I had tried .getValues() before, and putting a quote solves that issue! I am looking for a result that will not put all the multiple values in the same cell, but that each result from the multiple values would be in a new row, but that each of the new rows would have the one value from sheet on in the first cell of that row.  So close!

Comment: You'll need to put a second `For` loop inside the loop going through all the files.  So, you need a nested `For` loop inside the other `For` loop.

Comment: Thanks!  This is stretching my knowledge, but a great way to learn!

Comment: ok... I am very close now to what I am trying to do.  I have altered my code and show where I am stuck now!

Comment: I am going to mark this as answered and post another question as it has changed so much based on your help.  Thanks!